# Sagemaker true on-demand per second inference - like replicate

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I'm considering using Sagemaker instead of Replicate.com but also the learning curve has me wondering if I should just set up my own EC2 G/P instance (I could just docker clone my model's HF gradio api). Does Sagemaker work similar to Replicate (pay per second of inference/usage)?

Answer (score 0):

For SageMaker Real-Time Endpoints you are billed hourly depending on the hardware you have behind it. For example if you have a singular ml.t3.medium instance behind your endpoint you will be billed for the per hour rate of that instance. You can find more details at the SageMaker Pricing page: https://aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/pricing/

Comment: so if you run it for just 1 minute, you have to pay for the entire hour? is there a way that it can stop automatically when idle for 5 minutes. and how long does it take to restart it programmatically on demand?

Comment: AWS Sagemaker now has serverless inference...but I don't think anyone knows how to copy what replicate.com does and port to sagemaker?...

Comment: for real-time inference you will be billed for the hardware, with serverless inference it's on a number of inferences basis. Currently with real-time inference you can't scale down to zero instances behind an endpoint.